# Change Visual Studio Code's window title when using the "custom" title bar style?

Tags: visual-studio-code, window, titlebar, vscodium

In Visual Studio Code (or VSCodium), when using the (relatively new?) Window Title Bar Style (`window.titleBarStyle`) set to `custom` (which is the new default), the title bar of the window appears to ignore the setting of Window Title (`window.title`).

Specifically, and previously, one could change the title of the window to show the entire path to the workspace by adjusting the setting thusly:

```json
  “window.title”: “${activeEditorLong}${separator}${rootName}”
```

.. but that is clearly ignored, so all I'm getting in my title bar now is the name of workspace, which is the last component of the path.

Is there a different setting I should be adjusting?
Is this setting now theme dependent?

Comment: `"window.title": "${activeEditorLong}${separator}${rootName}"` works fine now. Does this issue still reproduce for you? Was the problem your weird quote characters?

Comment: Long delayed response, but yes it works now.  As for the quotes, I have no idea where they came from - I merely copied out of my settings and pasted here.  Perhaps something transformed them into "MS" quotes.    Regardless, having changed nothing since I first posted this over a year and a half ago, I can say that it's working now.  I probably wasn't patient.

Comment: probably a bug in an older version. unless you remember what version of VS Code you were running when you posted this, voting to close as "not reproducible".